# MultiValueDictKeyError - trying to learn Django from video tutorial "wikicamp"

Tags: python, django

I have used this board to find many answers to my problems but this one I can not find a post for.  I am certain I must just have some bad code.  I am new to web development so I am learning all of it (HTTP, HTML, Python and Django all at once, I do have more than 20 years programming experience so I get it).   I am at a point in the training video many of you know about where I am POSTing the new content without error from the edit html but it would appear the string data "content" is not being passed forward to the next stage where it would get saved into the database.  Thus far all the errors I have had are related to the fact the training was written in a very old version and I am using a newer version.  This one however I think is my fault so I need some help.  I think in my views.py I am not passing the "content" string properly or I am not passing the key to the database entry because the error seems to be that in the next section the "save" view the first line is throwing this error stating it can not find the string of data I was trying to pass from the last view. the error is ...

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:7000/wikicamp/tony/save/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"Key 'content' not found in <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'a9be0ebf915fc40b13b016e791a153be']}>"
```

Trace Back

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:7000/wikicamp/tony/save/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wikicamp.wiki',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Trace back:

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "D:\web dev\training\Django\secondproj\wikicamp\..\wikicamp\wiki\views.py" in save_page
      30.   content = request.POST["content"] # error thrown for this line of code
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
      256.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))

    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /wikicamp/tony/save/
    Exception Value: "Key 'content' not found in <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'a9be0ebf915fc40b13b016e791a153be']}>"
```

view code

```
def view_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page=Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response("create.html", {"page_name":page_name})
    content = page.content
    return render_to_response("view.html", {"page_name":page_name, "content":content})

def edit_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        content = page.content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        content = ""
    return render_to_response("edit.html",{"page_name":page_name, "content":content},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def save_page(request, page_name):

    content = request.POST["content"] # error thrown for this line of code
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        page.content = content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        page = Page(name=page_name, content = content, date = date)
        page = Page(name=page_name, content = content)
    page.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name +"/")
```

Comment: I'm surprised that's working at all. In both views, you're only returning a response in the exception. If the try block succeeded, Django would blow up. Also, for these types of issues, you need to post the entire traceback. The error is almost never in the final line, that's just where it finally bubbled up.

Comment: yea I thought that was weird to but that is how his video goes.  I am fairly sure I have it just like in his video.    The real deal is if the page does exist it never gets here so maybe that is why his tutorial is running.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not many truly up-to-date books/tutorials on Django. Most new ones focus on 1.0+ but there have been major additions in both 1.2 and 1.3. In particular, class-based generic views are the new hotness in 1.3, and if you're just starting out, that should really be what you're using. Regardless, though, if this is the actual code for this particular tutorial, you definitely need to find *something* else, because the author doesn't know what he's talking about even for previous versions.

Comment: Well, at the very least, post the bit of the traceback that actually includes files in your project. Somewhere there is most likely what's killing it.

Comment: how do I edit the original post top add the code you want to see?

Comment: There should just be a link to 'edit' at the bottom of your post.

Comment: for some reason the first time I hit edit it brought up a window that only allowed me to delete information not add.  the second time after I rejected the changes it is allowing me to add stuff.

Comment: No it was my fault for that I did it wrong.  I thought he had the indents wrong so I switched them up but he had them differently so that it works. It is a trick so that you will edit pages if they exist.  I will fix it above.  I don't think that matters for the question I have though...let me go try.

Comment: Here is the original git repo that the video tutorial is using, https://github.com/cmac0tt/wikicamp You can do a git clone to get the files, $ git clone https://github.com/cmac0tt/wikicamp.git Credits: [cmac0tt](https://github.com/cmac0tt/wikicamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes much more sense with full trace, though I should have seen it before just with your example code.

The "content" key only exists in `request.POST` after the page has been posted. It looks like you're using a separate view for the POST, though, so it should be in there. Nevertheless, you never want to directly reference a key in a dictionary that you're not 120% sure is in there. Instead, use `dict.get`:

```
content = request.POST.get('content')
```

That will store `None` if the key isn't set. You can also specify a default value:

```
content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
```

Comment: you have Parentheses () but the video is using brackets[]...When I leave it like the video I get an error on that line for 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable...but when I use your method I get a different error but at least on a later line as it is making it past this one. maybe I should start a different question for the new error I have on the page.save() line

Comment: No, I'm calling `get()` whereas the video is using subscript (`[]`). They serve the same purpose, retrieving the value from the dict.

Comment: I think this only pushed the problem farther down.  Now I get an error on the page.save() line near the end stating "integrity error"..."content may not be null." so I think the "get" is working but retrieving Null data so again maybe in the edit I am not saving anything.

Comment: Then, you need to figure out why "content" isn't being posted. Without seeing all of your code, including templates, I can't say for sure. Make sure that `save_page` is never called without a POST, view the source of the page and make sure you in fact have a field with `name="content"`.

Comment: Thanks I think I should just start a new post and throw that stuff up.  Odd though because in the class Page defined in my models.py the content = model.TextField(blank=True) so it should be okay to have null data anyway.  When you save "view the source of the page" do you mean the edit.html that you enter the data into?  The save_page view itself is not associated with a html file.  It is supposed to grab the data posted from the edit and response redirect to the new file.  Also there are 2 pieces of data name, content and they are not the same. The html has a text area assigned to content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get modify the code like this

```
    content = request.GET['content']
```

and it should work. I also used the tutorial and faced the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `save_page` view can be rewritten like this, which will avoid the error you get as well:

```
def save_page(request, page_name):

    Page.objects.get_or_create(name=page_name,
                               content = request.POST.get('content', ""))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name +"/")
```