# How to get the value of a HTML form text field into a Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jquery-ui

I want to get the value of a html text field `name="slider_value"` back into a Django class SessionWizardView, specifically into the `get_context_data` method. From reading around on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243560/django-detailview-how-to-use-request-in-get-context-data) and others I understand I need to use `self.request`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188299/1214163) I found `slider_value = self.request.POST['slider_value']` but it only returns a "None" value. I am guessing this is because there is no value in the text field at the time.

My problem is that I only want the value of `slider_value` stored when the user clicks submit on that form page.

**Can anyone tell me how can I get the value of the html text field `name="slider_value"` into my get_context_data method after the user has clicked the submit button?**

Below is my code so far

**views.py**

This is a shortened version of my get_context_data method

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                          
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']:

            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
                image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
                images.insert(step - 5, image)        
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            if step == 5:      
                print 'you are on step 5'         
                slider_value = self.request.POST['slider_value']              
                print 'This is the slide value', slider_value

           ....
           ....

    return context
```

**html**

This is my html form, I am trying to get the value of the text field names 'slider_value'. It corresponds to a jQuery slider (value -100 - +100)

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}"/>     

    <div class="slider" id="one"></div>                             
    <div id="slider-result"></div>   
    <input type="text" name="slider_value" id="hidden1"/>                           
    <script src="{% static "survey/js/slider_two.js" %}"></script>

    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
```

**slider_two.js**

This is my jQuery slider. It updates the above text field, `slider_value`

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var username = $('#hidden').val();
    if (username == "") username = 0; 
    $.post('comment.php', {
        hidden: username
    }, function(return_data) {
        alert(return_data);
    });
});

$(".slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: -100,
    max: +100,
    step: 1,

    slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
      if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
          $("#hidden1").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

As always, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value you need a request, you can use self.request. Just initialize a form and get it from there.

As a reference you could use this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) in the docs.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
    form = myForm(request.POST or None)
    return context
```

Comment: Based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16243717/1214163 and the docs it references it should be possible to use request in get_context_data by using `self.request`

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering The key part to making this work is that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your `click` listener, where you tried to ge slider_value you are referencing the wrong id, it should be `$("#hidden1")`;

Second, in your `post` Ajax call, you sent `slider_value`'s value  as parameter name `hidden`, and in your view, you tried to get it by name 'slider_value', it should be 'hidden'. Or you can change it in your Ajax call to 'slider _value'.